# Num.to_bytes - OverflowError: int too big to convert

Tags: python, byte

In order to convert **-10947726235** into byte array I ran:

```
Num = -10947726235
ByteArray = Num.to_bytes(4, byteorder='little', signed=True)
```

I got:

```
OverflowError: int too big to convert
```

Can you please advise?

Comment: Sounds like it’s too big.  Try a bigger number of bytes?  (The first arg, which you gave as only 4.)

Comment: What do you need help with? That number doesn't fit in 4 bytes, just like the error says. For tips, check out [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Four bytes can only represent a negative number of -2 billion-ish or lower.

```
>>> int.from_bytes(bytes([0,0,0,0x80]), 'little', signed=True)
-2147483648
```

You need five bytes or more to represent your number:

```
>>> Num = -10947726235
>>> Num.to_bytes(5, 'little', signed=True).hex(' ')
'65 f4 76 73 fd'
```